# Is there a way to get application icon (by a given package) from the web?

Tags: android, icons, google-play

I know it is not pure android question, but i'll try anyway.

Im building a website where I get package name of many applications (which is on the market).

I need a way to give a package name, and get back its icon.

Is there a way to do this?
from the market? apprain? or any other link

something like getting the favicon by this link:

http://g.etfv.co/https://facebook.com

http://g.etfv.co/https://google.com

---

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The [terms](http://play.google.com/about/terms.html) of use prevents the use of robots or other web scrapers:

> Blockquote
>   3. Your Use of Google Play
>   ...
>   3.3 You agree not to access (or attempt to access) Google Play by any means other than through the interface that is provided by Google, unless you have been specifically allowed to do so in a separate agreement with Google. You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) Google Play through any automated means (including use of scripts, crawlers, or similar technologies) and shall ensure that you comply with the instructions set out in any robots.txt file present on the Google Play website.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this API for the Android Market

http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

Or you could try to scrape the page (probably like this api does) but why do the work if it is already done...